# Endianness when it comes to widening/narrowing data

Tags: mips, cpu, cpu-architecture, endianness

I've been reading about endianess again, after a few months with MIPS. I'm a little confused when it comes
to when it matters when loading/storing from/to memory, so can someone verify If my understanding is correct? I don't have a Big Endian machine to test it and for some reason can't get qemu to work.

```
Example 1:

    lw $t0,word_ 
    word_: .word 0xAABBCCDD // behaves the same in both Endian and Little Endian

Example 2:
    
    lw $t0,bytearr_
    bytearr_ : .byte 0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF, 0xAA // either 0xABCDEFAA on BE or 0xAAEFCDAB on LE (?)

Example 3:
    
    lhw $t0,b2hw
    b2hw : .byte 0xAB, 0xCD //can this lead to issues as well? (LE is 0xCDAB, BE is 0xABCD)
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong or if I missing any potential conversion that could go wrong from one endianness to the other. Thanks!

EDIT:
What is going to happen in the case of LE/BE if I attempt to load a word into a halfword or a halfword into a word? For instance `lw $t0, hw_` where `hw_: .half 0xABCD` and `lhw $t0, w_` where `w_: .word 0xAABBCCDD`

Comment: FWIW, usually widening and narrowing refers to something else: converting what is already a byte into a word or what is a word into a byte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Example 1 the assembler is taking care of how to arrange the word in memory.

If the architecture is little endian the lowest address will hold `0xDD`, then `0xCC`, then `0xBB` and then `0xAA`.

If the architecture is big endian it will be the other way round: first `0xAA`, then `0xBB`, then `0xCC` and then `0xDD`.
So when you issue `lw $t0, word_` you get the value you expect (`0xAABBCCDD`).

On your second example you are defining an array of bytes, so the assembler must obey your ordering. The lowest address will hold `0xAB`, then `0xCD`, then `0xEF`, then `0xAA`.

So when you issue `lw $t0,bytearr_` you will get different results whether your architecture is little endian or big endian.

If your architecture is little endian you end up with `$t0=0xAAEFCDAB` and if your architecture is big endian you end up with `$t0=0xABCDEFAA`.

The third example is similar to the second. You define an array of bytes, so the lowest address will hold `0xAB` and then `0xCD` and issuing `lhw $t0, b2hw` will end up with `$t0=0xCDAB` if the architecture is little endian and `$t0=0xABCD` if it is big endian.

If you wish to let the assembler manage the arrangement then you would use the directive `.half`, like so:

```
lhw $t0,b2hw
b2hw : .half 0xABCD //let the assembler figure out how to arrange this half word in memory
```

---

Your final question about what happens when you "attempt to load a word into a halfword or a halfword into a word?".

The answer is that you really don't load a word into a halfword nor a halfword into a word. You load a word or a halfword starting at some address.
So if you have the following example:

```
hw_: .half 0xABCD
w_: .word 0xAABBCCDD
```

this code:

```
lw $t0, hw_
```

will load a word starting at the address pointed by `hw_`, and

```
lhw $t0, w_
```

will load a half word starting at the address pointed by `h_`.
The arrangement in memory would be (from smaller addresses to larger ones):

if its little endian:

```
0xCD  ; hw_
0xAB
0xDD  ; w_
0xCC
0xBB
0xAA
```

so if you issue `lw $t0, hw_` you would get `0xCCDDABCD`, and with `lhw $t0, w_` you would get `0xCCDD`.

And if it was big endian:

```
0xAB  ; hw_
0xCD  
0xAA  ; w_
0xBB
0xCC
0xDD
```

so if you issue `lw $t0, hw_` you would get `0xABCDAABB`, and with `lhw $t0, w_` you would get `0xAABB`.

Comment: I am a bit confused. In the last two, shouldn't LE and BE be opposite? For example in the second one, `0xAB` is in the lowest address, so in LE shouldn't it be the least significant byte?

Comment: Also one (or two) last questions. What is going to happen in the case of LE/BE if I attempt to load a word into a halfword or a halfword into a word? For instance `lw $t0, hw_` where  `hw_: .half 0xABCD` and `lhw $t0, w_` where `w_: .word 0xAABBCCDD`

Comment: @pol: you really don't load a word into a halfword nor a halfword into a word. You load a word or a halfword starting at some address.

Comment: sorry for my poor phrasing. I meant what i've written in the edit. Isn't that endianness dependent as well?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your follow up, cleared up everything. So all in all, going from one type to the other is typically risky then when it comes to Assembly level since going from one endianness to the next will most likely produce diffrent results?

Comment: @pol: indeed you would get wrong values if your assembler targets an architecture with one endianness and you end up executing with the other